# How to conditionally render a large number of properties in a panelGrid

Tags: jsf, facelets

I would like to render a group of name-value only if a value is not null (or another condition). This group of name is among other names and values which are always rendered.

To format the page, I use a `<h:panelGrid columns="2">`.

If I use a `<h:panelGroup rendered='thecondition'>` the alignment does not work. I tried `<ui:fragment>` and it didn't work either.

The group contains a large number of values and I would like not to add a rendered attribute for each name and each value of the group. Is there another solution?

Comment: What exactly did not work with `ui:fragment`? Maybe code example?

Comment: It's the same problem as with panelGroup: the format is not good (the names in a column and the values in another column) because the fragment is considered as a unique component.

Comment: You might need to go with a build-time tag as `c:if`...